# Is there a way to measure wifi or data connection strength on mobile?

Tags: cordova, http, cordova-plugins, wifi

I'm working on a project with Ionic v1, Cordova, and AngularJS 1.5. I notice that sometimes if the wifi signal is very weak the HTTP requests are still attempted but the data packets are lost and the user can lose their data sometimes.

Is there a way to measure the connection strength and then not proceed if it's not strong enough?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to events:

```
document.addEventListener('online', function() {
    this.isOnline = true;
});

document.addEventListener('offline', function() {
    this.isOnline = false;
});
```

In most real-life cases, they are fired even when the connection is too weak to download any packets

Comment: Well how about a measure of the strength if it is online?

Comment: You can use `navigator.connection.downlink` to get some sort of idea of connection strength

Comment: It only works on Android at the moment but it does look great.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem days ago. While I could not find best solution. I have created a new cordova plugin that you can use to get most of the basic network informations you need in cordova project or Ionic app project.

All you have to do is to run this command

*cordova plugin* add `cordova-plugin-network-signal-strength`

Usage The API has only one method `window["networkSignalStrength"].networkInfo(infoType, callback)`

*infoType* parameter could either be:

**null :** to get all the network details including signal strength, network type and connection state

**CONNECTION_STATE :** to get only the connection state which will return 0 or 1.

- 0 : disconnected
- 1 : connected

**SIGNAL_STRENGTH :** to get only the signal strength information. This return an object which include `rssi, rssq, rssnr, rsrp, signal level and lte level`

*signal type range:*

- RSSI: [-113, -51, "dBm"]
- RSSNR: [-20, +30, "dB"]
- RSRQ: [-34, 3, "dB"]
- RSRP: [-140, -43, "dBm"]

**NETWORK_TYPE :** to get type of connected network. Return integer -1 to 5

- -1 : unknown
- 0 : disconnected
- 1 : WIFI
- 2 : 2g
- 3 : 3g
- 4 : 4g
- 5 : roaming

**code snippet**

```js
// to get full network information

window['networkSignalStrength'] ? .networkInfo(null, (networkInfoData) => {
  console.log('network signal data :', networkInfoData)
});

/**
  You receive -1 as a result if the device is unable to get a known network 
  type and 0 for offline or disconnected state.
*/
// to get only signal strength
window['networkSignalStrength'] ? .networkInfo("SIGNAL_STRENGTH",
  (networkInfoData) => {
    console.log('network signal data :', networkInfoData)
  });

/**
  You should call the window.SignalStrength.dbm only after cordova platform is 
  ready. Example in Ionic framework:
 */

// ensure platform is ready before calling the plugin method
$ionicPlatform.ready().then(() => {
  // Platform now ready, execute any required native code
  setInterval(() => {
    window['networkSignalStrength'] ? .networkInfo(null, (networkInfoData) => {
      console.log('network signal data :', networkInfoData)
    });
  }, 5000)
});
```

[cordova-plugin-network-signal-strength](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-signal-strength)